# android Canvas.drawVertices crashing no exception

Tags: android, canvas, draw

I'm trying to draw a quadrilateral using Canvas `drawVertices` method.
It crashes every time with this line :

```
private final float[] verts = new float[] {
        0, 0,                   // 0 Top left
        0, 800f,                // 1 Bottom left
        480f, 800f,             // 2 Bottom right
        480f,0f                 // 3 Top right
    };
/* Order to draw the vertices */
private short[] indices = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };
private final int[] colors = new int[] {
        Color.parseColor("#75AADB"),
        Color.parseColor("#75AADB"),
        Color.parseColor("#75AADB"),
        Color.parseColor("#75AADB"),
        Color.parseColor("#75AADB"),
        Color.parseColor("#75AADB")
};
```

And finally I call the actual draw method:

```
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);

canvas.drawVertices(Canvas.VertexMode.TRIANGLES, verts.length, verts, 0, null, 0, colors, 0, indices, 0, indices.length, paint);
```

Comment: What is the logcat output when it crashes?

Answer (score 1):

Late, but try adding two `Color.parseColor("#75AADB")` to your colors array. `verts.length` must be equals `colors.length`